# Unable to change title bar color

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, window, colors

This is the current title bar with no effect from the theme
[image: Current title bar]

This is the title bar I expect with the sample theme

[image: Expected]

I am unable to change my title bar color and theme. I use Ubuntu tweak, unity tweak, compiz. Any theme I change, the title bar color does not change at all and uses the ambiance color (AFAIK). I have seen this issue before and I think I did reset of gnome themes, icons (not sure though), but now this does not seem to affect the color (or theme if you may call it) of the title bar.

Comment: I tried multiple things like rm -rf ~/.config/dconf, reinstall themes, unity tweak, etc. Nothing worked yet.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had that problem, I found that you needed to change the window manager. Try searching for a window manager and change it through that. Tho, It may not be there, as I am on XFCE and not Unity.